# Ubuntu 14.04: LXD PPA no longer available

Tags: 14.04, ppa, snap, lxd

It appears the LXD PPA for Ubuntu 14.04 was removed at the end of 2017. Unfortunately there's no migration path for a 14.04 as I'm not seeing how to get snaps installed for 14.04.

I'm not sure how to proceed here. What's the best way to move forward outside of upgrading to 16.04?

Comment: What do you mean "I'm not seeing how to get snaps installed for 14.04"? Have you tried just `apt install snapd` and then `snap install lxd`?

Comment: Seems there's several guides online that still refer to "snap" or "snappy" and not "snapd". I installed snapd and installed lxd. I then installed lxd backports and that seems to have restored my machine to sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LXD is a container manager for system containers.

To install LXD in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install lxd
```

LXD is a container manager for system containers. It offers a REST API to remotely manage containers over the network, using an image-based workflow and with support for live migration. Images are available for all Ubuntu releases and architectures as well as for a wide number of other Linux distributions.

LXD containers are lightweight, secure by default and a great alternative to virtual machines.